# Node.js 15 dependency problem with pullstate 1.20.x

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i want to use pullstate.js in my react project but it seems to be impossible to use it with the Node.js 15.
I have tried it in Node.js 13 and there it works. Can Anybody help?
In this example i created a plain react app and try to add the dependency.

**package,json**

``

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0",
    "pullstate":"1.20.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

``

This ist the rror i get after npm install.

```
    code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^16.12.0" from pullstate@1.20.1
    npm ERR! node_modules/pullstate
    npm ERR!   pullstate@"1.20.1" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately due to NPM version 7 being way more strict about peer dependency mismatches.

To get the old behaviour, run `npm install` with `--legacy-peer-deps`, as they say in the error message.

---

I've just released Pullstate version 1.21.0 - this has set a more broad peer dependency for React, including ^1.17.0 - I think this should solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the release 1.21.0 that fixed the problem!